# Is iphone simulator geolocation features working with the Ethernet/Wired network connection only?

Tags: iphone, geolocation, ethernet

I'm trying to develop an iPhone application which uses the geolocation libraries. Is this feasible for the iphone simulator to simulate the GPS functionality without the use of my PC's Wi-Fi infrastructure? Does anyone know if the iphone simulator can spot your location using your IP-address only (so only the Ethernet cable connection is required)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should test that functionality on an actual device. I believe the simulator will always show Cupertino, CA as the location.

Answer (score 1):

No it won't work using ethernet. Core location appears to only work with WIFI even though at the end is the same router.

Comment: I've had this exact situation. I had to turn wifi on just to get my location.

Answer (score 0):

CoreLocation doesn't work in the simulator, but there are options

http://github.com/futuretap/FTLocationSimulator

Answer (score 0):

Simulator doesn't have this functionality, but iSimulate has (it's not mine :-( ). It connects the device and simulator per WiFi and sends location events to the application within simulator: real GPS events and a few predefined locations around the world. Pretty cool!